# How to remove unused .NET framework / Core reference in GitHub projects with Visual Studio 2017+?

Tags: visual-studio

After I opened a GitHub project, the referenced Dependencies in Solution Explorer is like as following:

[image: Reference Libraries in Solution Explorer]

There are errors in error list:
[image]

I don't really use .NET 5.0 or .NET Core, how can I remove this from the reference?

Result after **Update-Package** Command, errors still exist.
[image]

Comment: This may solve the problem: Run this command on package manager console: Update-Package -reinstall

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages

Comment: @fatihyildizhan Thanks for the link, I ran the command but the issue persist. I don't think I'm using Nuget Packages? I directly download the zip from GitHub and loaded into the project solution. Is this not I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which version of VS you're using. It's possible to you don't have .NET 5 installed, which would explain the failure in resolving its assemblies.

If you don't need the .NET 5 target, you can remove it from the project file. To do so, edit the project and remove `net5.0` from the `<TargetFrameworks>` property.